# How to write multiple equations in mathJAX, like I did in LATEX?

Tags: latex, blogger, mathjax

I am new to mathJAX. I want to write math code in a blog in blogger.com .

After some researching, I found out that to use math equations in blogger, I have to stick this piece of code in the *head* section of the theme :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/latest/MathJax.js">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
 extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
 jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
 tex2jax: {
     inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
     displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
 },
 "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
});
</script>
```

After doing this, I am able to write math code like this

```
$ some equation $
```

or this

```
$$ some equation $$
```

but I am unable to write the equations in separate lines like this

```
$$
... \\
... \\
$$
```

I am also unable to use the **align** block to write multiple equations in one block.

In latex, I used to do

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
begin{align*}
& ... \\
& ... \\
end{align*}
```

In blogger, this is not working. I also tried doing this :-

```
$$
\begin{align*}
&... \\
& ... \\
\end{align*}
$$
```

None is working. What am I doing wrong and what should I do to write multiple equations in one block like Latex ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what solved the problem but I think after I used the HTML view instead of Compose view to write math codes the problem is solved.